# I wanted to make a frame by frame animation, in android studios for an app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-animation

The videos code I want to replicate in Kotlin, I was able to follow it for most of it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=scZYIAZrMWk&t=192s

The only problem I believe I have is how to use the ***AnimationDrawable*** function, it's in Kotlin, I can call to it; however, how it's used in the video is not how it's used in Kotlin since the video is in java.

I tried finding how it's used in kotlin, but no beans, I keep getting the way it's used in java even though I'm searching for kotlin.

I am trying replicate this line exactly: *AnimationDrawable diceAnimation;* which works only for java.

I'm new to programming so I thought maybe *Var diceAnimation = AnimationDrawable()* might work. It didn't work but wasn't an error, but it's not correct either. I know it wasn't right, writing it.

Here's the code without it:

```
package com.wedontprogram.devilsdice

import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        
        var dealerDiceView1 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.dealerDice1)
        dealerDiceView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice_animation)
        diceAnimation = dealerDiceView1.background()
    }
}
```

Comment: ``AnimationDrawable diceAnimation;`` is just defining a variable and its type, it's not creating an object. The Kotlin equivalent is ``val/var diceAnimation: AnimationDrawable`` - the IDE will usually convert Java you paste in to Kotlin, but it's a good idea to be familiar with some Java basics since you run into it a lot

Answer (score 2):

That Java code is defining a member variable named `diceAnimation` (well, `wifiAnimation` in the video) of type `AnimationDrawable` with an initial value of null (that is implicit), and then inside `onCreate()` it is assigning `dealerDiceView1.background()` to that variable. Since the type of a view's background is only reported as being a `Drawable`, they have to cast the returned value to the more specific `AnimationDrawable` type to be able to assign it to that variable. Java casts items by preceding the item with the type in parentheses.

Kotlin does not have member variables. It has properties instead. Since this `diceAnimation` never needs to be null and we set its value in `onCreate()` it is appropriate to make it a `lateinit var` property so we don't have to give it an inititial value. So we can give it a type of `AnimationDrawable` instead of `AnimationDrawable?`. You want to avoid using nullable types whenever you can because they are harder to work with and more error-prone.

You also have to cast the returned value when assigning it, for the reason I mentioned in the first paragraph. Casting is done with the `as` keyword in Kotlin.

If you are unfamiliar with what casting is, it is basically telling the compiler that you promise that some object is of a more specific type than the compiler knows, so the compiler can start treating it like that more specific type. In this case, since a View's background can be any type of Drawable, at the time you get the background, the compiler only knows that it's a Drawable. By casting it to AnimationDrawable you promise the compiler that you know that the background actually is specifically an AnimationDrawable, and then the compiler will allow you to assign it to variables or properties of that more specific type.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var diceAnimation: AnimationDrawable

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        
        var dealerDiceView1 = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.dealerDice1)
        dealerDiceView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dice_animation)
        diceAnimation = dealerDiceView1.background() as AnimationDrawable
    }
}
```